# Weird question, antiderivative and integral

Tags: integration

Given that $F(x)$ is the antiderivative to the function $f(x) = x^2 * ln(x)$ which satisfies that $F(1) = 7/9$, calculate $F(2)$.

How does one do that? I first figured that I would calculate the general $F(x)$, use the condition that $F(1) = 7/9$ to find $C$, then calculate $F(2)$... but it seemed too messy, and I am supposed to do this quickly and without calculators. Is there a trick or something I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried partial integration?

Comment: That's what i mean though. Partiel integrate, isolate C given my condition, then using my specific antiderivative to calculate F(2)... I am just asking if there's another way that perhaps would be more suited if I am supposed to do this rather quickly? Otherwise, if it's just like I said, then I guess that's that...

Comment: Partial integration is quite fast in this case, isn't it? What do you mean by "quickly"?

Answer (score 2):

You can find $F$ by using partial integration:
\begin{align*}
\int x^2 \cdot \ln x dx = \frac{x^3}3 \ln x - \int \frac{x^3}3 \cdot \frac1x dx = \frac{x^3}9 (3 \ln x - 1) + C.
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\frac79 = F(1) = -\frac19 + C,$$
so $C = \frac89$. Now it is easy to see that
$$F(2) = \frac89 (3 \ln 2 - 1) + \frac89 = \frac83 \ln 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is sound.

Try integration by parts: $u = \ln x \implies du = \frac 1x\,dx.$ $\quad dv = x^2 \implies v = \frac 13x^3$.

$$\int x^2 \ln x \,dx = \frac 13x^3 \ln x - \frac 13 \int x^2 \,dx$$

The remaining integral is a cinch. 
Note that $F(1)$ evaluates nicely (since $\ln(1) = 0$), which you can use to solve the invariable constant of integration.

I don't think there's any way around actually integrating and evaluating.